# ubuntu 12.10 updates fail

Tags: update-manager

This is what I get. should I uninstall/reinstall Ubuntu?  Is there a simple fix?  I'm a computer novice.

```
Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_27.0.1453.110-r202711_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2607:f8b0:4003:c02::5d 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-common_5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::14 80]
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the output of `sudo apt-get update` .

Answer (score 1):

The package seems to have been pulled out of the repositories. Run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then try again.

If that don't work, make sure that in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` you aren't mixing different repositories.

If you are using 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal), seems that you have some repositories that are for 12.04 (Precise Pangolin), replace all the repositories that are pointing to Precise to Quantal. You should verify this issuing:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep -v $(lsb_release -c | awk -F ' ' '{print $NF}')
```

If you found lines that do not correspond to your distribution, replace the wrong release target. In this command we are assuming that `precise` should not being here, you should replace `precise` with some other word. **This is dangerous, you should edit the file by hand using `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`**. Proceed under your own risk.

```
sed -i 's/precise/'$(lsb_release -c | awk -F ' ' '{print $NF}')'/g' test
```

Comment: Sorry, it is Ubuntu 1204 LTS. After reading several suggestions I figured it out. So for really uninformed people like me, this was my fix: Press CTRl+ALT+T. (Opens command window). Then enter: sudo apt-get updates. Then enter (password).Allow to run, then close window. Then run Update Manager. Updates are working fine now. Thank you.

Comment: @Ken That is exactly what Braiam said - please accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

Seems this repository is offline. Try to use another one they are found in the

> /etc/apt/sources.list

file. Just uncommend another repo and perform a:

> apt-get update

Further info can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine).